# Best way to display start time and duration (since the start time)?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, labels, time

**Some context:**

I'm trying to display the start time, and the duration since that time, in a single label. These timestamps are for urgent issues that need to be dealt with immediately.

I'm leaving towards the second option, since it shows how long the issue has been open for first, then the timestamp if needed for troubleshooting.

[image: Time + Duration Variations]

I'm curious to hear what you think. Thanks!

Comment: Does the End time come into the scenario?

Comment: It might, but that's not my main concern. Once the issue is closed, the label would change to:

**Issue Duration**
Open from Jun 13, 2016 at 4:55 PM to Jun 13, 2016 at 8:55 PM (for 4 hours)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

What's the typical and expected duration where these issues are open?

If they're suppose to be dealt with very rapidly, i.e. within minutes, Then option two showing duration first is helpful to emphasize that.

On the other hand, if tickets are dealt with more in the days range or months, then the duration itself is less important. Difference in durations are less salient once you deal with larger numbers. You'll want to put the start date time before the duration.

Comment: They usually should be dealt with within minutes. Maybe hours, rarely days. I feel like the second option would work best, thanks!